# Bias variance tradeoff

Tags: machine-learning, variance, bias, mse

In this context, are bias and variance always related to MSE, or only when the cost function for the statistical learning method is related to MSE?

Comment: In which context?

Comment: In the context of machine learning "bias variance tradeoff" question

Comment: Although this question seems to be arising from a confusion, it is possible to answer (+1 to @StudentT below). IMO, it can stay open.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're totally confused. Bias/variance relates how well your model fits relative to overfitting and underfitting. MSE is simply one of the many possible measures we can use to quantify how well a model performs.

High bias can be measured by very high MSE and high variance can be measured by very low MSE.

Comment: *Low* bias would normally be associated with *overfitting*. Think about Lasso or ridge regression where bias is induced to avoid overfitting.

Comment: @RichardHardy I think I've given the wrong orders, edited.

Comment: I was looking on wikipedia at "Bias–variance decomposition of squared error" from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bias%E2%80%93variance_tradeoff). I thought bias and variance "exist" only when we talk about MSE. So, reading your answer, it is not. Thanks! :)